# Using a template for loop to create a table, getting copy of the header for every record

Tags: django

I have a for loop in django templates.

```
{% for regel in regels %}

        <table style="margin-left: 40px" class="tg">

            <tr>
               <th style="width: 50px" class="tg-0lax">{{ regel.0 }}</th>

               <th style="width: 100px" class="tg-0lax">{{ regel.2 }}</th>
            </tr>

        </table>
```

How can I get 1 header for the whole table, because if I put in a header i creates the header for every iterations. So every row gets the same header.

Answer (score 1):

```
   <table style="margin-left: 40px" class="tg">
      <thead>
           <th style="width: 50px" class="tg-0lax"> Colum 0 </th>
           <th style="width: 100px" class="tg-0lax"> Colum 2</th>
      </thead>

{% for regel in regels %}

      <tr>
            <td style="width: 50px" class="tg-0lax">{{ regel.0 }}</td>
            <td style="width: 100px" class="tg-0lax">{{ regel.2 }}</td>
       </tr>

{%  endfor %}

     </table>
```